# how to only get the date in this format (year-month-day) or (day-month-year)?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema, date-format

I have the index.ejs file to output the books object like this:

```
<tbody>
          <% for (let i = 0; i < books.length; i++) { %> 
          <tr>
            <td><%= i+1 %> </td>
            <td><%= books[i].name %> </td>
            <td><%= books[i].author %> </td>
            <td><%= books[i].date %> </td>
            <td>
              <a href="/update-book?id=<%= books[i]._id  %> ">
                <span><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></span>
              </a>
              <a href="/delete-book?id=<%= books[i]._id %> " >
                <span><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <% } %> 
        </tbody>
```

Then, I use this form below to type the all the details and use a post request to save the data in mongodb including the date:

```
      <form action="/api/books" method="POST">
        <div>
          <label for="date">Date</label>
          <input type="date" name="date" value="" placeholder="" />
        </div>
     </form>
```

The schema model of the data object looks like this where I used the type for the date as 'Date'

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  date: {
    type: Date,
  },
  ...
})
```

The date gets saved in the database like this: 2022-02-22T00:00:00.000Z.

If I use type: String, then it gets saved in the database like this: Tue Feb 22 2022 06:00:00 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time).

But I only want to save the date in this format: yyyy/mm/dd

How do I do that?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to save it as `yyyy/mm/dd`?  There are many advantages (filtering, sorting, indexing, etc.) to saving ai as a `Date` object.  Conversions could be done after retrieving the `Date` from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the `$dateToString` aggregate pipeline operator.
For example, you might want a date to be returned in `mm/dd/yyyy` format instead of the long `ISODate()` format that includes minutes, seconds, milliseconds, etc

The `$dateToString` operator converts the Date object to a string, and optionally allows you to specify a format for the resulting output.

Let's see this in code:
Suppose we have a collection called `cats` with the following documents:

```json
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Scratch", "born" : ISODate("2021-01-03T23:30:15.123Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Meow", "born" : ISODate("2019-12-08T04:00:20.112Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Fluffy", "born" : ISODate("2020-09-24T10:45:01.007Z") }
```

We can use `$dateToString` to return that document with the dates in a different format.

We are able to format the date by using the format parameter. This is an optional parameter that allows you to use zero or more format specifiers to indicate how the date should be formatted.

Suppose we want date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format:
Here’s an example that converts the dates to `dd/mm/yyyy` format:

```js
db.cats.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project: {
          _id: 0,
          formattedDate: { $dateToString: { format: "%d/%m/%Y", date: "$born" } }
       }
     }
   ]
)
```

Result:

```json
{ "formattedDate" : "03/01/2021" }
{ "formattedDate" : "08/12/2019" }
{ "formattedDate" : "24/09/2020" }
```

You can also use the `$dateToParts` operator to return a document that contains all the various date parts separated into their own field.
I think that answers your question.